# When i Reload rows of a particular section , Other sections are also reloading ,why?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a total of 5 sections in the table view. All cells are xib. My problem is when I reload the rows of section 2, the other sections (especially section 3 and 4) are also reloading.

Section 0 has 1 row.
 
Section 1 has 1 row.
Section 2 has 1 row.
Section 3 and 4 has 3 rows.

All the section rows have different sizes.

Here is my code for reloading the rows of section 2.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2];

    if ([[_myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [_myTableView beginUpdates];
        [_myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]
                                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [_myTableView endUpdates];
    }
});
```

Comment: can you remove being update and end update then try please,

Comment: Would you mind pasting more of your tableview code?  It's possible that something else is happening at the same time as reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, which is reloading the other sections.